# CSS: Add fixed number of pixels to width and height on hover

Tags: css, css-transforms

How can I add a fixed number of pixels to the initial height of an element?

Pseudo-CSS:

```
.zoom {
  padding: 0px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  width: <initial-width> + 4px;
  height: <initial-height> + 4px;
}
```

When I use `transform: scale(...)` instead, the resulting difference is dependent of the initial size of the element, which I don't want. I am intending to use this on buttons and their initial size will depend on the contents on them.

Also, I don't want the contents to scale with the button.

In the following snippet you see the problem:

```css
.container {
  margin:  10px 100px 10px 100px;
}

.zoom {
  padding: 0px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="zoom">Short content</button><br />
<button type="button" class="zoom">Very very very very very very very very very long content</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

In fact, I want a look like `transform: scale()` (in terms of not affecting the neighbors), but by a number of pixels in each direction and not by a factor.

Comment: why not add a `padding: 2px` on hover?

Comment: What you are asking can only be done using Javascript.

Comment: add `padding: 2px` moves the button around, unfortunately.

Comment: how would I do that with JS/TS most efficiently?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say you want to increase the width and height but then say that you don't want to 'move the button around'. Could you describe more what you want to happen when you make it bigger? Do you want it say to look like a scale in the sense it doesn't alter the positioning of its neighbors (but without increasing the text size?).

Comment: Exactly: I want it to look like a scale (in terms of not affecting the neighbors) but by a fixed number of pixels, instead of a factor.

Comment: Are you allowed to alter the HTML?

Comment: sure, I have got full control, also React...

Answer (score 3):

You can add `padding-block` to your element on hover if you want to increase just the height and maintain its original width.

```css
.container {
  margin:  10px 100px 10px 100px;
}

.zoom {
  padding: 0px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s padding; /* Add this for smooth transition of height */
}

.zoom:hover {
  padding-block: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="zoom">Short content</button><br />
<button type="button" class="zoom">Very very very very very very very very very long content</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's going in a good direction. However, I actually want a look similar to `transform: scale()` (regarding not to affect neighbours positions) but by a fixed number of pixels instead of pixels instead of a factor.

Comment: I'd suggest using Javascript for that as it would be more efficient. You can refer to this for a similar solution using jQuery: [Animate height and width on hover using jQuery](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-animate-div-width-and-height-on-mouse-hover-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the final result using just CSS but there is a little wrinkle during the transition.

This snippet is put here in case it helps in your specific situation, and hopefully someone can refine it (probably with JS).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      margin: 10px 100px 10px 100px;
    }
    
    .zoom {
      padding: 0px;
      transition: all .2s linear;
      --margintop: 10px;
      margin-top: var(--margintop);
    }
    
    .zoom:hover {
      --padding: 2px;
      padding: var(--padding);
      --minuspadding: calc(-1 * var(--padding));
      margin: calc(var(--margintop) + var(--minuspadding)) var(--minuspadding) var(--minuspadding);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="zoom">Short content</button><br>
    <button type="button" class="zoom">Very very very very very very very very very long content</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The hovered element has padding set to 2px which will increase its width and height by 4px overall. To compensate for that its margins are set with the relevant amounts so that the following elements' positions aren't affected.

CSS variables are used to specify the initial margin top (you have it as 10px) and the extra padding required (2px) just to make it easier for you to change these amounts if you want. CSS calc is then used to calculate the adjusted margins.

The wrinkle during the transition is that for a split second the following elements positions are affected but they end up in the right place.